# How to extend ftl display template in alfresco share?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have the following xml customisation to deploy my customisations declared:

```
<module>
    <id>Global changes</id>
    <auto-deploy>true</auto-deploy>

    <!-- Enhance individual WebScripts when their paths match -->
    <customizations>
        <customization>
            <targetPackageRoot>org.alfresco</targetPackageRoot>
            <sourcePackageRoot>fr.mypackage</sourcePackageRoot>
        </customization>

    </customizations>
</module>
```

and I'm trying to add an additional CSS to header.get.html.ftl so I created, under the following path, webscripts/fr/mypackage/components/header/ a header.get.html.ftl and added the following to it :

```
<@markup id="css-additional" target="css" action="after" scope="global">
    <@link href="${url.context}/res/themes/${theme}/css/global-header.css" group="header"/>
</@>
```

But the css isn't added to the header. Am I missing an important step here?
**Edit**: I should add I'm working on 4.2.e if this helps.

Comment: try adding it to main ftl rather then header ftl as alfresco is probably in process of removing header file usages.

Comment: I meant to say that the file itself is the main file for the header component. I am not overriding the deprecated header.get.head.ftl but instead the header.get.html.ftl. Which is the main template itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they changed it in 4.2, take a look at http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/developer/2013/09/04/customizing-the-share-header-menu-part-1/

Here the source package should be: `<targetPackageRoot>org.alfresco.share.header</targetPackageRoot>`

Comment: So it's not possible to target the components package and mirror the directory structure? I was hoping to be able to do this as I have several components to override as well as stuff not under components. Thanks for replying anyways